# TSQL- How to count number of instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I need to know which set of students have an action code used only once, and which students have an action code used more than once.

[image]

I'm trying to see if a student has more than one of 5 action codes.
e.g.

```
SELECT StudentID 
FROM #T 
WHERE ActionCode IN (51201,51206,51207,51208,51209)
```

How would I code this please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you try anything? like `Count()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried Count, but I don't know how to use it the way I need to.  I have 5 Action codes I'm trying to see if a student has more than one of.  I simplified the answer above hoping I could modify it to do what I need.  I have the 5 response codes in a WHERE IN (...)

Comment: SELECT StudentID
  FROM #T
  WHERE ActionCode IN (51201,51206,51207,51208,51209)

Comment: Thanks @DhruvJoshi, I was working through SQL Fiddle to better understand what you did.  It's a good answer and helps, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   StudentID,
   ActionCode,
   ActionCodeCount = Count(*)
FROM
   dbo.StudentActionCodes
WHERE
   ActionCode IN (51201, 51206, 51207, 51208, 51209)
GROUP BY
   StudentID,
   ActionCode
ORDER BY
   StudentID DESC,
   ActionCode
;
```

### [See this working in a live demo at SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c8138/1)

Given this set of values (including some unwanted ActionCodes):

```
StudentID   ActionCode
----------- -----------
987654      51201
987654      51206
987654      51207
987654      51208
987654      51209
987654      51210
987653      51201
987653      51208
987653      51208
987653      51211
987652      51201
987652      51206
987652      51206
987652      51207
987652      51208
987652      51209
987652      51212
987652      51213
987651      51201
987651      51206
987651      51209
987651      51209
987651      51214
987651      51215
987650      51201
987650      51201
987650      51201
987650      51201
987650      51208
987650      51208
987650      51216
```

Here are the results:

```
StudentID   ActionCode  ActionCodeCount
----------- ----------- ---------------
987654      51201       1
987654      51206       1
987654      51207       1
987654      51208       1
987654      51209       1
987653      51201       1
987653      51208       2
987652      51201       1
987652      51206       2
987652      51207       1
987652      51208       1
987652      51209       1
987651      51201       1
987651      51206       1
987651      51209       2
987650      51201       4
987650      51208       2
```

You might also enjoy this query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   dbo.StudentActionCodes S
   PIVOT (
      Count(S.ActionCode) FOR S.ActionCode IN ([51201], [51206], [51207], [51208], [51209])
   ) P
;
```

Which gives this result:

```
StudentID   51201       51206       51207       51208       51209
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
987650      4           0           0           2           0
987651      1           1           0           0           2
987652      1           2           1           1           1
987653      1           0           0           2           0
987654      1           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: Thanks @ErikE, this worked!  I'm assuming the Count(*) is looking to the WHERE clause.  If I had two aggregations and I used the Count(*), how would it know which to count?

Comment: What do you mean by "two aggregations"? The `Count(*)` simply counts the number of rows that were "collapsed" as defined by the `GROUP BY` columns that had the same set of values.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query:
SQL fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1dc6/6

It gives sum of same type of actions per student as well as sum of all allowed actions per student

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    StudentID, 
    Actioncode,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID,Actioncode  ) as [Count_of_this_action_instance],
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID  ) as [Count_of_all_action_instance] FROM StudentActionCodes 
WHERE ActionCode IN (51201,51206,51207,51208,51209)
```

Comment: Using my SQL Fiddle, or even copying the code from my SQL Fiddle, is in my mind rude. Please do your own work.

Comment: @ErikE Thank you for the fiddle. I upvoted your answer and then copied your fiddle create data. I'll be sure to not repeat in future.

Comment: @ErikE I also want to let you know - that as a fellow SO user I admire you very much. Thank you for helping everyone. I really hope imitation is best form of flattery.

Comment: I would of course defer to the community's thoughts on copying fiddles, but  I can't find anything on meta about it. Thank you for the compliment!

Answer (score 0):

count and group by

```
SELECT
   StudentID,
   Count(*) as 'count'
FROM
   dbo.StudentActionCodes
GROUP BY
   StudentID;
```